# Enclose values in double quotes in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this string in vb.net.
I would appreciate if you can let me know how I can enclose the values in double quotes

```
dim str as string=""
str.Append("EmpID=" & empNo & " DeptID=" & deptID & "")
```

I want the value of string to be EmiID="10" DeptID="20"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double double quotes to get a single double quote in the string

```
str.Append("EmpID=""" & empNo & """ DeptID=""" & deptID & """")
```

Answer (score 3):

ControlChars.Quote is nice to use :)

dim metatransferString as string = ""

Answer (score 2):

Just use double double quotes like:

```
dim str as string=""
str.Append("EmpID=""" & empNo & """ DeptID=""" & deptID & """")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ControlChars.Quote

```
dim str as string=""
str.Append("EmpID=" & cControlChars.Quote & empNo & ControlChars.Quote  & " DeptID=" & ControlChars.Quote  & deptID  & ControlChars.Quote)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a pretty old question. But I used it this way

```
str.Append(String.Format("EmpID={0}{1}{0} DeptID={0}{2}{0}", Chr(34), empNo, deptID))
```

If empNo = 10 DeptID = 20, it would give EmpId="10" DeptID="20"