# How to add only 1 " in String

Tags: vb.net, quotes

this might be a super easy question but it is not. I am wondering how to put only a single " in a string 
Example

```
 Dim eg as String
 eg = ""W"
```

It just does not seem to work. Is there any special characters for it as i need to add in codebehind for my VB.

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541250/enclose-values-in-double-quotes-in-vb-net

Answer (score 5):

If it's Visual Basic you need one more `"`:

```
Dim eg as String 
eg = """W"
```

If it's C#, use the \ escape character: `"\"W"`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5.aspx

Comment: You can also manually insert the ASCII char, like this: `"She said, " & Chr(34) & "You deserve a treat!" & Chr(34)`

Comment: Awesome :) You should hit the checkbox next to my answer to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 3):

Just double it:

```
Dim eg as String
eg = """W"
```